# Como mostrar uma div e esconder as outras com Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Olá, tenho o seguinte código que esta funcionando mas quero melhorar ele. 
Alguma sugestão?

> add evento de click

```
[1, 2, 3].forEach(num => {
  document.getElementById(`btn-lupa${num}`).addEventListener("click", () => {
    esquemaLupa(num);
  });
});
```

> função ocultar `div`

```
function esquemaLupa(num) {

  if (num == 1) {
    document.getElementById(`feed-lupa-${num}`).style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById(`feed-lupa-2`).style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById(`feed-lupa-3`).style.display = "none";
  }

  if (num == 2) {
    document.getElementById(`feed-lupa-${num}`).style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById(`feed-lupa-1`).style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById(`feed-lupa-3`).style.display = "none";
  }
  if (num == 3) {
    document.getElementById(`feed-lupa-${num}`).style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById(`feed-lupa-2`).style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById(`feed-lupa-1`).style.display = "none";
  }

}
```

Html

```
<button id="btn-lupa1">1</button> 
<button id="btn-lupa2">2</button> 
<button id="btn-lupa3">3</button> 
<div id="feed-lupa-1">div1</div> 
<div id="feed-lupa-2">div2</div> 
<div id="feed-lupa-3">div3</div>
```

Comment: cade o código HTML?

Comment: Cara use uma classe .ativo e aplica só no elemento clicado e retira dos irmãos. Colocar `.style.display = "none/block";` não é uma boa escolha...

Comment: seria tipo isso mesmo:

<button id="btn-lupa1">1</button>
<button id="btn-lupa2">2</button>
<button id="btn-lupa3">3</button>
<div id="feed-lupa-1">div1</div>
<div id="feed-lupa-2">div2</div>
<div id="feed-lupa-3">div3</div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Há várias formas de melhorar o código a nível de CSS e HTML (como por exemplo, usar classe em vez de id), mas dá pra melhorar o código JavaScript simplificando a função:

```
function esquemaLupa(num) {
   document.querySelectorAll("[id^='feed-lupa-']").forEach( (e)=>{ e.style.display = "none"; });
   document.getElementById(`feed-lupa-${num}`).style.display = "block";
}
```

O `document.querySelectorAll("[id^='feed-lupa-']")` seleciona todos os elementos que começam com o id `feed-lupa-` e os oculta, em seguida exibe apenas que tiver o valor em `num`:

```js
[1, 2, 3].forEach(num => {
  document.getElementById(`btn-lupa${num}`).addEventListener("click", () => {
    esquemaLupa(num);
  });
});

function esquemaLupa(num) {
   document.querySelectorAll("[id^='feed-lupa-']").forEach( e=>{
      e.style.display = "none";
   });
   document.getElementById(`feed-lupa-${num}`).style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<button id="btn-lupa1">1</button>
<button id="btn-lupa2">2</button>
<button id="btn-lupa3">3</button>
<div id="feed-lupa-1">div1</div>
<div id="feed-lupa-2">div2</div>
<div id="feed-lupa-3">div3</div>
```

> Só precisa se atentar para não usar outro elemento que comece com o id
>   `feed-lupa-` exceto esses `feed-lupa-1`, `feed-lupa-2` e
>   `feed-lupa-3`.

## Utilizando class

Utilizando `class` em vez de `id` fica bem mais fácil e evita possíveis conflitos de `id`:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.btn-lupa').forEach((e,i) => {
  e.addEventListener("click", e => {
    esquemaLupa(i);
  });
});

function esquemaLupa(i) {
   document.querySelectorAll('.feed-lupa').forEach( e=>{
      e.style.display = "none";
   });
   document.querySelectorAll('.feed-lupa')[i].style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<button class="btn-lupa">1</button>
<button class="btn-lupa">2</button>
<button class="btn-lupa">3</button>
<div class="feed-lupa">div1</div>
<div class="feed-lupa">div2</div>
<div class="feed-lupa">div3</div>
```

Veja que os parâmetros do `forEach` `(e,i)` retornam o elemento (`e`) e o índice (`i`), e na outra função você usa o `i` como índice para mostrar a div com respectiva classe que possui o índice `[i]`.

Comment: opa!
Eu estava chegando perto aqui entao! Comecei a testar o querySelector pra fazer os esquemas. Ajudou  muito. Valew. Vou estudar esse seu código! att

Comment: Blz. Acrescentei na resposta uma solução usando classes.